# C# Monogame - Change tint color on hover

Tags: c#, button, xna, monogame

I want to have a class that has the purpose of managing buttons in my game. So far I have the following code:

```
public class Button
{
    private SpriteFont btnFont;
    private string btnTxt;
    private Vector2 btnPos;
    private Color btnColour;

    public Button(SpriteFont newFont, string newTxt, Vector2 newPos, Color newColour)
    {
        btnFont = newFont;
        btnPos = newPos;
        btnTxt = newTxt;
        btnColour = newColour;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(btnFont, btnTxt, btnPos, btnColour);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
private Button btn_1;
private Color colour = new Color.CornflowerBlue;
private Rectangle buttonArea_1 = new Rectangle(24, 300, 192, 39);
// LoadContent() Method:
btn_1 = new Button(Game1.defaultFontBig, "Play Game", new Vector2(24, 300), colour);
// Update() Method:
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Point mousePosition = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
if (buttonArea_1.Contains(mousePosition))
{
    colour = Color.Yellow;
    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Game1.currentGameState = Game1.gameStates.loadingScreen;
    }
}
else
{
    colour = Color.CornflowerBlue;
}
// Draw Method():
btn_1.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

But something goes wrong... When I test the game and I hover on the button it doesn't change its color from cornflower blue to yellow but still changes the game state as I click on it. I feel like this is some kind of simple initialization thing I'm missing so I'm asking for your help. Any code examples/approaches explained would be great.

**EDIT:**

Via properties like this?

```
public Color Colour
{
    public get { return colour; }
    private set { colour = value; }
}
```

But the does the usage change? Can I still pass in the colour to the constructor and change it in `Update()`?

Comment: Where does buttonArea_1 get initialized?

Comment: Also, changing the variable colour wont affect the button. You need to expose the button colour as a property via get/set

Comment: You can update it by btn1.Colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

`private Color btnColour;`

in the button class, do this:

`public Color btnColour { get; set; }`

then in the usage code, instead of this:

`colour = Color.Yellow;`

do this:

`btn_1.colour = Color.Yellow;`

and:

`btn_1.colour = Color.CornflowerBlue;`